# addobserver / removeobserver query

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsnotification

Is it OK to use `-removeObserver:` first and then call `-addObserver:` with the same name? Or is it a rule to have `-addObserver:` first before `-removeObserver:`?

I tried it using OS 4.0 and it seems OK (no crash, warnings... etc.).

```
-(void) setObserver
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:OBSERVER_NAME object:nil]; 

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector: @selector(selectorName)
                                             name:OBSERVER_NAME 
                                           object:nil]; 
}
```

The reason is to prevent two observers with the same `selectorName` method being called twice assuming that `-setObserver` method was called again if its inside `-viewDidLoad` and a memory warning was issued.

Also, do I need to invoke `-removeObserver:` during `-dealloc`?

Comment: +1 good question.
I dont' know if it's save to remove an Observer that was not registered before, but I know it's a must to remove the observer before deallocing.
For your given case you could also remove the observer in viewDidUnload. That's what this method is for: Balancing all calls made in loadView and viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting `-selectorName` invoked twice, there's probably some other issue with your code.  And even if Cocoa will be graceful about removing observers you haven't added yet, I wouldn't actually do that.

As user tonklon says in a comment, you should probably remove the observer in `-viewDidUnload`.  As to your last question, it's also reasonable to remove the observer in `-dealloc`, though it's good practice to structure your code such that things like removing observers happen at a deterministic time rather than as a side-effect of memory management.